# how to use use first() and last() for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a UL with some LI in it. when I create the statically I can use first() and last() method to get the for example first li and then get offset of that by offset() or outerwidth() but when I create them dynamically then I get the following error:

cannot read property of undefined

Here is where I create my ul and li's inside:

```
for (var entity in jsresult){


        //$(".entity"+temp).empty();
        //$(".entity"+temp).attr("id","entity"+jsresult[temp].id);
        $("#enbartop").append("<li  id='entity"+jsresult[temp].id+"' class='entities entity"+temp+" jquery-shadow jquery-shadow-lifted'>   <div class='main'><div class='entity_titlebar'><div id=\"entityTitle"+temp+"\"" +
                " class=\"entity_titlebar_title\">"+jsresult[temp].name+"</div><div id=\""+jsresult[temp].id+
                "\" class=\"entity_titlebar_data\">"+jsresult[temp].freq+"</div><div id=\"entityTitleBar"+jsresult[temp].id+"\" class=\"entity_titlebar_toggle\"></div></div><div id=\"entcon"
                +temp+"\" class=\"entity_content\"><div id=\"en_logo"+jsresult[temp].id+
                "\" class=\"en_logo\"><img src=\"images/entities/"+jsresult[temp].id+"\"></img></div><div id=\"en_bars\" title=\"en_bars"+
                temp+"\" > <div class=\"en_bar"+jsresult[temp].id+"_1\"></div><div class=\"en_bar"+
                jsresult[temp].id+"_2\"></div><div class=\"en_bar"+jsresult[temp].id+"_3\"></div><div class=\"en_bar"+jsresult[temp].id+"_4\"></div></div></div></div></li>");


        temp++;





    }
```

and here is where I use first() and last:

```
firstEntity = $(".entities").first();
lastEntity = $(".entities").last();
entityWidth = firstEntity.outerWidth();
```

Also it is noteworthy that #enbartop is my UL.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to do this after the html string is appended to the dom structure

Comment: Thanks You are right it is solved